# configure : error while installing graph-tool

Tags: ubuntu

I am tired of trying installing graph-tool on my machine with Ubuntu 14.04. After solving several issues, I am now getting the following error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (cairomm-1.0) were not met:

No package 'cairomm-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CAIROMM_CFLAGS
and CAIROMM_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Can anybody kindly tell me way out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the cairomm libs, try that

```
sudo apt-get install libcairomm-1.0-dev
```